# why are initializers getting errors when upgrading from Rails 2 to Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upgrade, initializer

This is in my config/initializer/string.rb:

```
class String  
 include ClearCompany
end
```

I have lib/clear_company.rb

That is where I have a module ClearCompany.

Comment: unidentified constant ClearCompany

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to require that file, as constants aren't autoloaded from `lib` in Rails 3:

```
require 'clear_company'
```

You could also add `lib` back to the load paths by putting this in your `Application`'s class:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

Comment: aw, I see....where should I put libs in the future if I don't put what you put in?

Comment: @Angela: put them in `lib` still, you will just have to manually require them like you would in any other Ruby library too. Rails has just hanged their behaviour to be more standard.

Comment: bigg I see, I used your auto_load paths as a solution so then I don't need to 'require' --- is that right?  thanks!